# RxJava best practice to emit list of self-emitting items

Tags: java, android, rx-java, reactive-programming, reactivex

I'm using RxJava to build a reactive UI in Android. Say I have a `ListView` or `RecyclerView` to display a list of users. I want to be able to feed my adapter the whole list of items, each at their most recent state, whenever any of them is updated.

Here is my current implementation of the idea:

1. Create an `Observable` for each user, which is a downstream of some hot `Observable`. So whenever there is a change, it'll be triggered by the hot `Observable` and in turn emits the most recent user data.
2. Use `Observable.combineLatest` to create a consolidated point where I'll combine the users into a list
3. Emit the list to UI

I am able to get it working, though at times when the list contains lots of users i.e. 1000 users, or when I need to dynamically update the list because of delete/insert (hence need to invoke `combineLatest` again), I observe a noticeable lag between an update happens and it ultimately emits the list.

So my question is, what is the best and most efficient way of implementing such list of self-updating items and emit as a whole? Or am I not supposed to emit in the form of list at all?